# Django - ListView - list assigned images to the post

Tags: python, django, listview

Hello I would like to list all images which were added to my post in my Blog application.

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     content = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)

class PostImage(models.Model):
     post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='postimages')
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery/')
```

I guess I should override the get_queryset method but dont know how. Any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT:

Views.py

```
class PostGalleryView(ListView):

    model = PostImage
    template_name = 'blog/gallery.html'
    context_object_name = 'images'

class PostListView(ListView):

    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        public_posts = Post.objects.all()
        return public_posts
```

Comment: please provide your views.

Comment: @binpy Views.py added

Comment: loop into your context object `images`. each iterator(x) has property `x.image` which is the relative path to your image. Then to display the image `<img src="{% static x.image %}">`. Btw. dont forget to `{% load static %}` in your django template file.